# RXJava and DialogFragment => Dialog waits for observable - why?

Tags: android, rx-java, android-dialogfragment

I show a `DialogFragment` and load data in the background. I want the dialog to show up, the data keeps on loading and incrementally updates the already visible dialog.

**Problem**

The dialog is not shown before the observable completes. Why?

**Code**

```
private final static Handler mHandler = new Handler();

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    Observable<List<Data>> observable =  Observable.create(new Observable.OnSubscribe<Data>()
    {
        @Override
        public void call(Subscriber<? super Data> subscriber)
        {

            // iterate and create data
            for (int i = resolveInfo.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--)
            {
                 Data d = ...;
                 subscriber.onNext(d);
            }

            subscriber.onCompleted();
        }
    })
            .onBackpressureBuffer()
            .buffer(150, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
            .filter(new Func1<List<Data>, Boolean>()
            {
                @Override
                public Boolean call(List<Data> rxSingleDatas)
                {
                    return rxSingleDatas.size() > 0; // only deliver not emtpy lists!
                }
            })
            .onBackpressureBuffer()
            .doOnNext(new Action1<List<Data>>()
            {
                @Override
                public void call(List<Data> shareDatas)
                {
                    // add result to list + notify adapter
                    for (int i = 0; i < shareDatas.size(); i++)
                        mData.add(shareData);
                    if (mAdapter != null)
                        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            })
            .doOnCompleted(new Action0()
            {
                @Override
                public void call()
                {
                    // flag to indicate all data is loaded
                    mReady = true;
                }
            });

    // subscribe on handler thread for async execution
    // observe on main thread for updating UI
    mSubscription = observable
            .subscribeOn(HandlerScheduler.from(mHandler))
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe();
}

@Override
public void onDestroy()
{
    if (mSubscription != null)
        mSubscription.unsubscribe();
    super.onDestroy();
}

@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    MaterialDialog.Builder builder = new MaterialDialog.Builder(getActivity())
            .title(R.string.share_with)
        .cancelable(true)
        .autoDismiss(false);

    mAdapter = ...;
    builder
            .adapter(mAdapter, new MaterialDialog.ListCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onSelection(MaterialDialog materialDialog, View view, int i, CharSequence charSequence) {

                    if (!mReady)
                        return;

                    // handle click
                }
            });

    MaterialDialog dlg = builder.build();
    return dlg;
}
```

**EDIT**

I replaced the handler with one that's running on the background thread, but this leads to following execption: `CalledFromWrongThreadException` when trying to update the adapter in the `doOnNext` call... I would say the `observeOn` should have the effect that the `doOnNext` is called on the main thread, but it seems, that this does not work...

Comment: `mHandler` points to a background thread?

Comment: I added the definition for `mHandler`... And no, it's not, so that's the reason for the behaviour... Let it run on a background thread will lead to a `CalledFromWrongThreadException` though although I observe on the main thread...

Comment: In your case `subscribeOn()` thread applies to everything in `Observable.create()`. `observeOn()` applies to everything after `observeOn()`, which is nothing here, you can remove this line.

Comment: Sorry, I meant: `subscribeOn()` applies to `Observable.create()` and everything downstream of it. I'm not sure which call `CalledFromWrongThreadException` points too, but you can try inserting `observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())` just before this call, and optionally go back on the background thread after this call with `observerOn(HandlerScheduler.from(mHandler))`.

Comment: The exception comes from updating the adapter in the `doOnNext` function... When using `observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()) ` should not ALL `do...` functions be called on the foreground process?

Comment: That's totally up to you on what thread to execute a particular operator. `observeOn()` works in a way that all operators that follow it are executed on the specified thread. And nothing prevents you from calling `observeOn()` as many times as you want in the chain to switch threads.

Comment: I'm aware that I can change it, but if I use it the way I do, should not ALL observations be done on the main thread? I'm using it that way very often and then I would just have luck until now that I make my UI updates afterwards... I try to explicitly set the observation thread before doing some observations... If I did not set an observation thread, which one will be the default? The same as the `subscribeOn` thread?

Comment: Yes, `subscribeOn()` applies the thread to the generating part (`create()`) and whatever goes after it until the first `observeOn()` or an operator that operates on a specific thread by design. So RxJava doesn't automatically switch threads until you explicitly tell it to.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, that solved the problem and helped me a lot

Comment: I'll post it as an answer if you don't mind.

Comment: Of course not, I'll accept it then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a little confusion about how `subscribeOn` and `observeOn` operators work.

`subscribeOn()` applies the thread to the generating part (`Observable.create()` here) and whatever goes after it until the first `observeOn()` or an operator that operates on a specific thread by design. Thus, `observeOn` switches the thread for operations downstream of it in the chain. RxJava doesn't automatically switch threads until explicitly told to.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification